# How to implement HOVER in fxml

Tags: javafx, hover, fxml

I wanted to change the style of a button when passing the cursor over it with fxml. I haven't found any place where it's explained for fxml, although the property exists in this language.

Thank you

Comment: Styles should be changed in CSS, not FXML

Answer (score 0):

> With **javaFX code**:

```
 //with hoverProperty
 button.hoverProperty().addListener(l->{
        System.out.println("Button is being hovered");
    });

 //or with mouseMoved
 button.setOnMouseMoved(m->{
      System.out.println("Button is being hovered");
    });
```

> With **css code**:

Let's say that your button has the **Id("BUTTON")**,to do this in code use this button.setId("BUTTON") then you can use:

```
#BUTTON:hover{     
  -fx-background-color:white;
  -fx-text-fill:black;
  -fx-font-weight:bold; 
}
```

for more about javaFX css you can check this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)